# Is the blender smoke engine able to do this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I love Andreas Barden's work and his been playing with TurbulenceFD with some [amazing results](https://www.instagram.com/p/BZleA11AqRn/). I'm wondering if we can do something similar with Blender. Is Blender's smoke engine able to do something like this? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why not. I'm not seeing anything particularly fancy going on in that sim. It appears to just be a spinning block emitting smoke that rises into a sphere.

Answer (score -3):

Cinema4D cannot accomplish such a smoke simulation, but it's the TurbulenceFD plugin for 399$. In the cinematic industry you find a lot of plugins for Maya, Cinema or Lightwave which are developed for special effects like explosion and smoke and they all vary between a few dollar to millions.

Sure if you are able to program python or another language then you can develop your own plugin and control particles in order to fly around a object. Maybe someday someone will write such a tool and give it to the community for free ;)

Comment: Could you people have the courtesy to write at least a comment explaining why you down vote a answer!